# How to avoid of using anonymous callback function for marker click event listener?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know there's lots of ways to do the click event handling for google map markers, I've been using those methods and they always work well.

But just curious that if we could do the same thing in a better way, I'm thinking about this because it's possible that there could be 100,000 markers in a new project (of course they will not be shown on the map at the same time, but the markers' instances do exist)

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', clickhandler);
function clickhandler(event) { /* HERE */ }

in the clickhandler's scope, we only have the latLng information, and I guess it's not reliable to search markers by latLng which are float numbers, so The problem is, what is the best way to find which marker was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever I am trying to reference one element out of a group elements (say, elements with the same class), using `this` can help find the right element that triggered the event. Just to make sure `this` wil work, I check with `console.log`.

`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', clickhandler); function clickhandler() { console.log(this); }`

This should log the marker object.

Comment: Thank you Ennui, it really helped me a lot, "this" is the marker!

Answer (score 2):

The mouse click event on a marker passes a [**google.maps.MouseEvent object**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) to the listener function, therefore:

```
// give the maker an id
marker.myId = 25;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', clickhandler);

function clickhandler(mev) {
    alert(mev.latLng); 
    alert(this.myId);// shows 25
}
```

Comment: I tried, but... I'll come back when I meet the minimum requirements for voting :-S, haha ^_^